# Add Resources to existing CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have a CloudFormation master stack. I want to write a tool that allows me to add Lambda functions to the master stack using Boto3.

In order to add the function to the stack I need to be able to

- Get Outputs from the master stack to use in the function's template.
- Add the Function to the master stack.

I have only been able to get this to work with:

- Build, zip, and upload the function to S3
- Add the function's template to the master stack's templates. (requires editing the master stack's files)
- Deploy the master stack.

I would like to be able to create the function without editing the master stack's files.

(i.e. `boto3.get_stack_id` -> `boto3.add_resource_to_stack_by_stack_id`)

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: What speaks against creating a complete new stack per Lambda functions which import values from master stack? I dont get the point why you try to change the master stack

Comment: The problem is getting the Outputs from the master stack. Now that you mention it that is probably possible with `describe_stack`? Edit: Hey! it works. This is definitely the call (pun). Its funny how in programming (and I guess in life) you cant solve the problem by looking at it from one direction but then someone says "hey, look at it this way" and you're like "ohhh!!!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not possible. When updating a stack, you always have to provide a URL for the new stack template, or provide the full template body as a string, or use the previous template.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html

There is no API call that allows you to directly add a resource to a stack.